# Ordenação de ranking de tempo

Tags: php, javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo que executa uma função em *JavaScript* que cronometra quanto tempo o jogador levou para terminar até chegar à última fase:

```
function formatatempo(segs) {
    var min = 0;
    va hr = 0;

    while (segs >= 60) {
        if (segs >= 60) {
            segs = segs - 60;
            min = min + 1;
        }
    }

    while (min >= 60) {
        if (min >= 60) {
            min = min - 60;
            hr = hr + 1;
        }
    }

    if (hr < 10) {
        hr = "0" + hr
    }
    if (min < 10) {
        min = "0" + min
    }
    if (segs < 10) {
        segs = "0" + segs
    }
    fin = hr + ":" + min + ":" + segs
    return fin;
}
```

No caso acima, ao final da execução a variável `fin` é retornada com o tempo percorrido. O problema, é que preciso armazenar estas saídas em um ranking, como poderia ordená-las de forma que pegue do menor para o maior tempo?

Comment: Se você retornar os resultados em timestamp fica bem fácil de ordenar, é so trazer do menor para o maior.

Comment: o problema é que eu não estou conseguindo fatiar a variavel que peguei do JS e passei pro PHP em um array :                                                     $fin = "<script>document.write(fin)</script>";         a função explode do PHP não aceita isso,

Comment: Cara isso é Javascript, não é php, você tem que saber diferenciar entre os dois. Além disso, a linguagem javascript é somente client-side e não server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer apenas pegar a quantidade de segundos que o cara gastou e exibir de uma forma legível, correto? Tipo, se eu gastei 65 segundos para resolver, você quer mostrar que eu gastei 00:01:05 correto? Já pensou em fazer assim:

```
function foo($seconds) {
  $t = round($seconds);
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($t/3600),($t/60%60), $t%60);
}

echo foo('290.52262423327'), "\n";
echo foo('9290.52262423327'), "\n";
echo foo(86400+120+6), "\n";
```

retorna

```
00:04:51
02:34:51
24:02:06
```

Answer (score 0):

Na linha `fin = hr + ":" + min + ":" + segs` dessa função, você garante que o retorno dessa função é uma string, da forma `HH:MM:SS`; então você pode fazer uma comparação de string direta para fazer o *sort*, utilizando a função [localeCompare()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp) e a [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).

Segue um fiddle de exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/pv4ojgp2/